# Flink: binlog transformation to multiple DTO and transformation method in flink

Tags: apache-kafka, flink-streaming, real-time-data, tidb

A newer to Kafka, Flink and Tidb.
Assume I have three source MySql tables `s_a`, `s_b`, and `s_c`, and want to collect records to target TiDb table `t_a` and `t_b` in a realtime.
The mapping rules are

```
`s_a`  --> `t_a`                   
`s_b` union `s_c`   ---> `t_b`  with some transformation (e.g., field remapping).
```

The solution I adopted is kafka + Flink with Tidb sink, where binlog changes are subscriped to Kafka topic; Flink consumes the topic and write the transformed result to Tidb. The problem for me in the flink code part  are:

1. how to can I  easily restore the json string (that has information of operatin, tables), polled from kafka, to different kinds of DTO operation (e.g, insert/creat `t_a` or `t_b` ). I have found a tool called `Debezium` as Kafka&Flink connector, but it looks like it requires equality between  the source table and the target table.
2. How to write the transformation `VKDataMapper` if i have multiple target tables. I have difficult in defineing the `T` as it can be `t_a` DTO(Data Transfer Object), or `t_b` DTO.

The existing sample code for me is like:

//The main routine.

```
   StreamExecutionEnvironment environment =
                StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
       //consume is FlinkkafkaConsumer. TopicFilter returns true. 
        environment.addSource(consumer).filter(new TopicFilter()).map(new VKDataMapper())
                .addSink(new TidbSink());

        try {
            environment.execute();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("exception {}", e);
        }
 
 
 public class VKDataMapper implements MapFunction<String, T> {

    @Override
    public T map(String value) throws Exception {
        //How T can represents both `T_a data DTO` `T_b`...., 
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you looked at https://github.com/ververica/flink-cdc-connectors? Perhaps it would simplify things.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try the Flink SQL? In this way, you only need to create some tables in Flink, and then define your tasks through sql like:

```
insert into t_a select * from s_a;
insert into t_b select * from s_b union select * from s_c;
```

See some examples in https://github.com/LittleFall/flink-tidb-rdw, feel free to ask anything which makes you confused.

Comment: Thanks @Littlefall. I saw the flink-tidb-rdw, yet, I will check it. Would you mind adding a wechat (I though i sent a mail to you previously)?

Comment: Yes! Very sorry to see this so late, I've just sent a friend request to you.